# Download attribute does not work when canvas dimensions are above 900px in html

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, download

I'm developing a web application that the user can download an image after done editing that image, and to do so, i draw the edited image into a canvas to obtain then a url to assign it to an `<a>` tag. Everything works fine but only if the dimensions of the canvas are below 900, otherwise, it shows a download failure. Is there any suggestion to prevent this error from happening?